# Compress-7zip each object

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I'm trying to generate a script that goes to the directory and compresses each file to .zip with the same name as the file.

I managed with the compress-archive, however it has limitations for files up to 2gb.

so searching, I found compress-7zip, but it uses different parameters.

```
$InputFolder= "C:\Temp\teste"
$OutputFolder="C:\Temp\teste"

#coletando arquivos
$CsvFiles = Get-ChildItem $InputFolder -Filter '*.xlsx'

#loop compactar arquivos
$CsvFiles | ForEach-Object { 
    $zipSetName =  $_.BaseName + ".zip"
    Compress-7zip -Path $InputFolder -Format Zip -ArchiveFileName $zipSetName
}
```

But I am not having success doing this with compress-7zip, the above script does not work hehe, am I passing wrong parameters? doing it manually works, however throwing all files into a single file.
could someone help me make the above script work, which compresses file by file.

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question! :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen maybe now hehe, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the function you mentioned [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PS7Zip/1.0.1.2/Content/Compress-7Zip.ps1), including the parameter names.

In this case, use

```
$CsvFiles | ForEach-Object { 
    $zipSetName = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.FullName, '.zip')
    Compress-7zip -FullName $_.FullName -OutputFile $zipSetName -ArchiveType Zip 
}
```

P.S. I used the `ChangeExtension` method here because both your input and output paths are the same. 
If that is not the case, use

```
$zipSetName = Join-Path -Path $OutputFolder -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + '.zip')
```

Comment: ( https://i.ibb.co/2jf4Sch/erro.png )
@Theo

Thanks for the answer.
I don't know why some parameters like OutputFile are giving an error, I tried to simplify the use, it runs as I want, but there is an error saying that the file is in use.

already reboots machine etc, but without success.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the FullName parameter

Comment: @TássioCarlini Without adding parameter `-FullName $_.FullName` the function tries to zip the zip file itself, hence the error message. Please use the code I answered.

Comment: i try, but:
Compress-7Zip : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FullName'.
At line:10 char:19
+     Compress-7zip -FullName $_.FullName -OutputFile $zipSetName -Arch ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Compress-7Zip],

Comment: @TássioCarlini then.. are we talking about the same function then? Please edit your answer and add the code of whatever you are using.